# How to Implement a Callback in JavaScript return Value with a Dictionary

Tags: javascript, dictionary, callback, alert, bootbox

I am trying to implement a JS Dictionary which has a key and value, where the value calls a callback function for validation.

For example I have tried defining an animalsDict dictionary.
When I try calling the "Dog" key to call the value validateDogSound() callback function, the bootbox.alert doesn't show.

What am I doing wrong? Is this how we do callback functions in a dictionary? Any tips or help? Thank you

```
var animalsDict = {
    Dog: validateDogSound(),
  //Cat: validateCatSound(), 
  //Bird: ... etc
}

function validateDogSound(){
 bootbox.alert("dogs bark!");  
 return false;
}

console.log('testDog', animalsDict["Dog"]);
```

Comment: If you want a reference to the function, you'll need to do something like `var animalsDict = { Dog: validateDogSound }` and then when you want to call it you can do `animalsDict["Dog"]()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **call** the function:

```
console.log('testDog', animalsDict["Dog"]());
//                                       ^
```

Also change the object to

```
var animalsDict = {
    Dog: validateDogSound,
  //Cat: validateCatSound, 
  //Bird: ... etc
}
```

Comment: I recommend accepting this answer over the other one, you definitely _don't_ need to declare functions before you use them (at least for function declarations, function expressions are another story)

Answer (score 0):

this way

```js
// "functions" first !

var validateDogSound = function()  
  {
  bootbox.alert("dogs bark!");  
  return false;
  }


var animalsDict = {
    Dog: validateDogSound ,  // no parenthesis
  //Cat: validateCatSound , 
  //Bird: ... etc
}
console.log('testDog', animalsDict["Dog"]() );  // with parenthesis
```

Comment: Why function first?

Comment: Thank you for the breakdown and comments!

Comment: @Nick you'r right, in this case this will work, but if she use complex objects calls, this is the only way

Comment: What is a complex object call?

Comment: @Nick Objects with methods, I also changed the function to const

Comment: I think that's even worse though, why would you recommend changing the function declaration to an arrow function expression?

Comment: @Nick, Ok, I put back to function happy ?

Comment: Not really, I think any answer that suggests he needs to put the function first is incorrect because it's not at all the source of his issue. The issue was that he was calling the function immediately in the object and he _wasn't_ calling the function later on in `console.log`. Position of the function declaration had nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Nick And I think the opposite, that all of these things have to be done in order and that is good advice. My remark on complex objects remains valid, you just wanted to nitpick because I changed the way of declaring the function, and I did it only to illustrate the reason for the order of the declarations, which by the way you do not dispute.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://bootboxjs.com/getting-started.html#bb-script-order), you need to load the javascript libraries in the following order.

> Since Bootbox is a wrapper around Bootstrap's modal functionality, you need to include the libraries in order:
>
> ```
> jQuery
> Popper.js
> Bootstrap
> Bootbox
> Bootbox Locales (optional - omit if you only need the default English locale)
> ```

Try adding these headers in the same order or use the following. I added the following in the header and looks like it worked. You will know better. **Please note I have not verified the urls, this is just for demonstration.** It is better if you have local copies of these on your server and are appropriately referenced in the head.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/5.5.2/bootbox.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var animalsDict = {
    Dog: validateDogSound(),
  //Cat: validateCatSound(), 
  //Bird: ... etc
}

function validateDogSound(){
 bootbox.alert("dogs bark!");  
 return false;
}

console.log('testDog', animalsDict["Dog"]);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```